# Weird lines between procedural meshes Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh, procedural-generation, perlin-noise

There are weird lines between the edges of the meshes. This is an image of the problem:
[image: A picture of the problem]
[image: Another picture of the problem]

Code:

```
    //ChunkSize is the length and width of each mesh(an integer. In this case, it is 100),
    //Vertices are the vertices array of the mesh,
    //ChunkPos is a Vector2 of the position of each mesh(for example, (0,0),(100,0),(0,100),(100,100)...),
    //scaleXZ is the scale of the mesh (Scale the mesh "Horizontally"),
    //and scaleY is the number that is going to be multiplied to the height, so the mesh can scale upwards. (Scale the mesh "Vertically")

    Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[(chunkSize + 1) * (chunkSize + 1)];
    for (int z = chunkPos.y, i = 0; z <= chunkPos.y + chunkSize; z++)
    {
        for (int x = chunkPos.x; x <= chunkPos.x + chunkSize; x++)
        {
            float y = Mathf.PerlinNoise((x / scaleXZ), (z / scaleXZ)) * scaleY;
            vertices[i] = new Vector3(x - chunkPos.x, y, z - chunkPos.y);
            i++;
        }
    }
```

I also use Universal Render Pipeline shader for the materials of these meshes.

How can I edit the code or do something to the shader to solve this problem?

Thank you for viewing my question!

Comment: Looks like a lighting/shader issue, not a mesh issue.

Comment: @Draco18s Thank you for replying so quickly! How can I edit the lighting/shader to make this work?

Comment: \*shrug\* not sure. I know a little about shaders, but I can't tell what might be wrong (you should add it to your question).

Comment: @Draco18s Me too... Ok, good suggestion!

Comment: Have you tried just calling RecalculateNormals ?

Comment: @LouisGarczynski Yes

Comment: Can you explain the meaning of `chunkPos.x + chunkPos`? By all rights it shouldn't even compile. You should also really check for off-by-one errors, many of these loops look like they should be using a `<` instead of `<=`

Comment: @LouisGarczynski That was a typo. I edited the code after copy-pasting to make it easier to read. I accidentally changed that one.

Comment: Can you post the actual code please. Or if you modify it, make sure it actually runs and still displays unexpected behavior.

Comment: As you are using chunks, the outter borders will not have another point next to them (every mesh is calculated for itself without taking the neighbours into account.). This will result in a "hard" edge and the normals are calculated without taking the next chunk into account. That is why you see seams.

Comment: Also this video might help
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4olmeStiBsE

Comment: @Dev.Tommy Why not write your answer?